# Show Notification in full screen

Tags: android-notifications

I want create custom ui notification and show it full screen. How can I do it.

```
<LinearLayout>
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/icon"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:src="@drawable/icon_image" />
  <TextView
        android:id="@+id/alarm_text"
        style="@style/white"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp"
        android:text="@string/in_progress" />
<RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/sticky_header"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/eader_height"    
        android:paddingBottom="10dp"
        android:paddingTop="10dp">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/sticky_text"
            style="@style/normal_white"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:text="@string/message" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/button"
            style="@style/white"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:background="@drawable/msg_selector"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/msg" />

    </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

I know there are RemoteViews we could use, but I am not sure how to set it up to  NotificationCompat.Builder

Also I need to take action(launch activity) when the user presses the button in id -> button

Comment: Sweety Bertilla were you able to do it the way you wanted?